# AutoHotkey push a button to move curser to the left

Tags: mouse, move, autohotkey

I am struggling to make an AutoHotkey script, if anyone would help I would appreciate it.
the script im trying to make is: if I pressed F my mouse would move to the left as long as im pushing the F button from the current location I had my mouse on. This is what I have right now and it's not working.

Loop {
  Sleep 10
  MouseGetPos,x
    if (MouseMove, -1000, 0, 100, R)
      send {C down} 
    else if {C up}
    break
}
return
Esc::ExitApp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
f::MouseMove -5, 0, 50, R
```

50 is the speed, and the R letter means that the offset is relative to the current cursor position. You don't need the loop, as the pressed key will generate subsequent events on its own.

Comment: this works but its really slow. I tried f::MouseMove -1000, 0, 100, R, But it goes on even if I release f.

Comment: The range for speed is 0..100, 0 being the fastest. You've tried the slowest possible value. Change it to 0, and I don't recommend using 1000 as offset, it's too huge.

Comment: I changed the numbers to f::MouseMove -150, 0, 1, R and its working fine. thank you very much.:)